# Solving the equation $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$, where $f(x) = x^{4}-5x^{2}+x+4$ for $x\leq-1.6$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Here's another question from an IB Math HL past paper -

> Consider the function -
>
> $$f(x) = x^{4}-5x^{2}+x+4, \;\;\ x\leq-1.6$$
>
> It is given that $f^{-1}(x)$ exists.
>
> Solve the equation $\; f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$

I have been working on this problem for almost an hour and can't figure out how to do this problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

NOTE: This is from a non-calculator paper.

Comment: [WA does not give an encouraging answer...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+function+of+x%5E4-5x%5E2%2Bx%2B4)

Comment: But $f$ is not one-to-one. Check for typos.

Comment: @quasi Nope, no typos. Have you taken the domain into consideration?

Comment: @Justin: I missed the minus sign on $-1.6$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the interval $x \leq -1.6$ the function is one-one so the inverse exists. The function and it's inverse are symmetric about the line $y=x$. So for $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, they should both intersect at the line $y=x$. Said differently, we need to find the intersection of the function $y=f(x)$ and the line $y=x$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
x^{4}-5x^{2}+x+4 & = x\\
x^4-5x^2+4&=0\\
(x^2-4)(x^2-1)&=0.
\end{align*}
This gives $x=\pm 1, \pm 2$ as the possible solutions.But in the interval speciifed, we only have $\boxed{x=-2}$.

Comment: What would be the inverse function of this specific function ($f(x)=x^{4}-5x^{2}+x+4, \;\;\ x\leq-1.6$)?

Comment: I guess this is OK for a high school problem, but this doesn't show why there aren't any other solutions besides those of $f(x)=x$. For instance, if $f(x)=1-x$, $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ has infinitely many roots, not just those of $f(x)=x$.

Comment: I don't think it's "OK" for a high school problem. Without further argument to show that the _only_ solutions are those for which $f(x)=x$, it gives the false impression that the set of real solutions to the equation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ is always equal to the set of  real solutions to the equation $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $f$ is invertible in the given domain, $f(x)=f^{-1}(x) \Leftrightarrow f(f(x))= f(f^{-1}(x))=x$. Therefore, $x$ a solution of $f(x)= f^{-1}(x)$ if and only if it is a solution of $f(f(x))=x$.

Comment: The "if" part is not automatic. For example, for $a\approx -2.068222165$, we have $f(f(a))=a$, but $f(a)$ is not in the restricted domain of $f$.